# regarding Singleton design pattern & c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Design Patterns: When to use the Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton)

in what kind of situation Singleton pattern will be used. please explain with real life scenario. thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern  (A singleton in C# is the same as anywhere.  Just read up on it.)

Answer (score 0):

I used it in a website that had a dynamically generated menu, that were shared by a group of users.

We generated the menu in memory, since we would loose performance if was read from the database every time it should be generated.