# Asp.Net Singleton Pattern scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.Net in what scenario i will use singleton as most of the job can be done with Session / Cache / Static by checking whether it is null nor not.

please refer to my previous question

[Singleton Pattern / Check for Null - While using Asp.Net with Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934427/singleton-pattern-check-for-null-while-using-asp-net-with-session)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are confusing the particular *implementation* of the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with the concept itself. Your previous question / implementation could be interpreted as Singleton within a user session, if you saved in the Application cache instead it would be a Singleton for the ASP.NET application.

Singleton just means that there is only one instance of a particular object at any time and this is enforced by the application - *how* you enforce this is an implementation detail that might vary depending on your choice of platform / language.

In particular for ASP.NET you may still use the standard singleton pattern for C# using a static variable (see [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)). There will only be multiple instances if your application is used in a web farm scenario, also refer to this SO thread: [Are static class instances unique to a request or a server in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194999/are-static-class-instances-unique-to-a-request-or-a-server-in-asp-net)