# How to enforce certain methods of Object creation?

Tags: java, singleton

I'm working with an abstract class and a (growing) set of subclasses of this class. For certain reasons all subclasses of A should implement the singleton pattern. During startup of the application there exists a `List<Class<? extends A>>` and I would like to initialize all singleton-instances.

From what I see, my option here is to go for Reflection, enforcing by guidelines that all A-implementing classes have to have a defined constructor and invoke that via `o.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();`.

I've also tried a different approach where I used overloading of static methods. That is, A defined a static `initialize` method and all subclasses had to reimplement that method. The call can again be invoked via reflection.

The first approaches has the obvious disadvantage that violations of the programming-guideline result only in runtime-errors, not in compile-time errors. The second is even worse, if a subclass does not implement the static method, only the method in `A` is called with no apparent exception thrown.

So: How do I enforce a uniform way to initialize in a set of singleton classes?

Edit:

A configuration-class generates a list of all children of `A` during startup, those classes can be either registered directly in the configuration class programmatically or configured via a configurationfile:

```
private void initModules() {
  Configurator.addModule("modulename", SubOfA.class);
  ...
}

private void initModuleFile() {
  ...
  String name = in.readLine();
  String classname = ...;
  String modulename = ...;
  Configurator.addModule(modulename, Class.forName(classname));
}
```

Comment: _During startup of the application there exists a List<Class<? extends A>> and I would like to initialize all singleton-instances_ <-- This is not clear to me, could you also give more detail with some scheme or even simple code?

Comment: You might also seriously consider whether a singleton is the right way to go. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/228380/151502 . Is anyone else going to see this code?

Comment: The singleton-classes are adapters establishing db-access to different databases. According to the cited answers, this would qualify as an acceptable use of singletons, as it synchronizes access to an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> those classes can be [...] configured via a configurationfile

In this case the common approach is like your first proposal: `Class.forName("...").newInstance()`

(This can, of course, be encapsulated by some kind of factory pattern.)

Since, in Java, you cannot enforce a particular constructor to be implemented by subclasses, the only viable way is to demand a default constructor by design guidelines/contracts.

As an example, have a look at Android's [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static
>   field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the
>   Parcelable.Creator interface.