# Should I use a singleton to keep track of my Google Analytic tracker instances?

Tags: android, google-analytics, singleton, tracker

I'm using V4 of the Google Analytics Library as provided by Google Play services.
Long story short: I find passing a reference to the tracker to all the components my application to be quite tedious. I know in previous versions of the library a Singleton for managing one instance was provided (EasyTracker) but no longer.

Would anyone know what the detriments are to putting a tracker in a singleton once the application starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one ever answered you, and I'm sure you figured it out. I've implemented this with a Singelton and it seems to work fine. If anyone else has the same question, I put my wrapper up on github. maybe it will save someone else some time:

https://github.com/uglyelf/android-helpers/blob/master/AnalyticsWrapper.java

Comment: hi! I figured this out a while ago and wrote something along the lines you did, i.e. build a simple API/wrapper on top of the hitbuilders which my app could then leverage where-ever it needed to. For being so kind as to reply, please have my upvote and the answer selected. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! And I'm glad to hear you did something similar. I was worried there was a hidden gotcha I was unaware of. But I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to find an answer to this question myself, the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton) gave me reason enough to pursue this approach:

> One reason that tends to come up over and over again on the internets is that of a "logging" class (which you mentioned). In this case, a Singleton can be used instead of a single instance of a class because a logging class usually needs to be used over and over again ad nauseam by every class in a project. If every class uses this logging class, dependency injection becomes cumbersome.

Along with @gregory-randolph's answer of course.