# Android global variable dynamic value

Tags: android, global-variables

Hello all i want to make use of a global integer variable that i shall be incrementing in 7 different activities according to the users right or wrong choise. The problem is that i every time i implement the variable in each different activity , the value is not kept. Instead i get the default value of the variable. What i want is that every increment i make to the variable is saved , when i use it again in the next variable. Any help appreciated.
I have tried and failed :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private int grade=0;

public int setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}
```

}

```
public class lessonOnePhoto extends Activity {

private int grade = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getGrade();

if (rbtn[0].getText().toString().equals("Boy")) {
grade++;
}
else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Choise",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grade` you are incrementing is local and private to your activity.  It is also a primitive, rather than an object, so `grade = .getGrade()` will set the local variable to the same value as the global value, it is not some kind of reference.

Instead, do something like this:

```
MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication());
myApplication.setGrade(myApplication.getGrade()++);
```

Or implement increment decrement methods.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private int grade=0;

public int setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void incrementGrade() {
    grade++;
}

public void decrementGrade() {
    grade--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to increment the original application value .. not the copy to maintain the variable in between the activities

```
if (rbtn[0].getText().toString().equals("Boy")) {
grade++;
}
```

change to

```
if (rbtn[0].getText().toString().equals("Boy")) {
((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).setGrade(grade++)
}
```

Comment: This won't work.  If grade is changed somewhere else, the activity will not have the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one method in application class to increment value

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private int grade=0;

public int incrementGrade() {
    this.grade = grade + 1;
}

public int setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}
}
```

and increment when needed

```
MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication());
myApplication.incrementGrade();
```

OR ================

Make that grade static and increment by accessing it in static way

```
 public static int grade = 0;
```

access it lie this

```
 MyApplication.grade ++;
```

Comment: It's bad practice to make variables public.  Instead, use getters and setters so that in the future, if the implementation of grade in the application changes (e.g. to shared preferences or a database) the rest of the code does not need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can [get the result from the activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) where the user enters the response and handle it from a MainActivity that manages all the responses.

Another option to avoid storing information in the Application class could be to have a [Singleton](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218) with a Shared Instance that stores the global variables. However, the use of singletons is considered a bad practice in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228380/2996064).