# use of singleton design pattern in real time java applications

Tags: java, singleton

I understand the singleton design pattern concept, but I never really come across implementing singleton pattern in java applications or web based applications. 
So tell me where we are using this approach in real time applications.

Comment: Have you tried to look for any implementation ? What have you come across ?

Comment: Do you mean real *life* applications or real *time* applications, which are a very specific class of applications?

Comment: This may help:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by the pattern, any time you want there to exist only a *single* instance of something, you would use the Singleton Pattern.

A common example might be a Logger object.  There could be many places throughout the system where one would invoke a logger to, well, log something.  But you may only ever need one such instance.  This can be particularly true if constructing the instance is a heavy operation.

Something like this:

```
public class Logger {
    private static final Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();

    private Logger() {
        // do something to initialize the logger
    }

    public static Logger getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    // implementation ...
}
```

Then any code which needs to reference the logger doesn't need to instantiate it (can't, in fact), and instead just uses the singleton:

```
Logger.getInstance().Log("some message");
```

Other real-world examples might include a dependency injection container, a read-only data access service (such as a lookup service which caches results), etc.  Generally anything where initialization or repeated operations can be heavy and which is thread-safe.

Comment: he already knows the pattern itself he wanted to know where it is most commonly used. but nice answer. ;)

Comment: @ChrisKo: Understood, but I figure for completeness I may as well be thorough.

Comment: why did you mark that as answer? i answered before him and i didn't provided an code-example since you said you know the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Singleton always makes sense when dealing with heavy objects where it makes no sense to have more than one instance across the whole application.
Since you are dealing with Web-Applications you should have been dealt with objects which are the same for each user/session/request. Database-Connection-Pool is probably a good example, or a Servlet. It doesn't make sense to create a new Pool for each request. One Pool for the whole application should be sufficient. Other examples are probably Loggers, Email-Client, Global-Settings, those things should be the same instances for each user otherwise you will run out of resources. Or did i get something wrong?