# java, as flliows,why does this global varaible of the program keep only an instance?

Tags: java

*Could the uniqueeInstance have one and only one instance?*

```
public class A {

     private static A uniqueInstance = new A();

     private A() {}

     public static A getInstance() {
            return uniqueInstance;
     }
}
```

Comment: You are looking at what is known as a `singleton`, which is an object (an instance of a Java class in this case) which has only one instance.

Comment: It might be useful for you to search the term "Singleton", what it's for and how to correctly implement it.

Comment: So, you're talking about singletons, I'd suggest doing some research on them.  In your case, no, it's possible that `uniqueInstance` might be assigned a new instance (but it will only ever have one) (I believe it has to do with how classloading can work). Generally speaking, it's generally considered a  better idea to use a `enum` now days

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Singleton** pattern, it's purpose is to have only one possible instance for a class.

This is why you have a private constructor , so that no other class can attempt to instantiate it directly.

Here are more elaborate thoughts for possible uses of a Singleton :

[When to use the Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed.

By reflection you are easy to get more instances.

The only way to guarantee that you have exactly one instance is to use an enum:

```
enum Holder {

    INSTANCE;

    //Keep in Mind of A you may still have more instances. if you want to have the
    //guarantee to have only one instance you may need merge the whole class
    //into an enum (which may not be possible)
    public A uniqueInstance = new A();    
}
```

Other ways like throwing an exception in the constructor are generally also possible. But not completely secure since there are ways to create an Object without calling any constructor.