# Is singleton pattern okay

Tags: android, design-patterns

I currently have an app where I use singleton pattern extensively.
i.e I have something like This. FeedHandler handles stuff relating to feeds like getting feeds(Posts) from a REST service, getting comments associated with the posts e.t.c.

```
public class FeedHandler{
  public FeedHandler feedHandler=null;
  public FeedHandler get(){
    if(feedHandler==null){
        feedHandler=new FeedHandler();
     }
  return feedHandler;
}
```

Then I make my network calls here with volley and publish the result with EventBus to subscribers.

```
 public void  getSingleFeedFromNetwork(final boolean force, final String feedId){
    VolleyHandler.get().makeJsonObjectRequest("feeds/single?id=" + feedId, Request.Method.GET, null, force, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Feed feed=GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(response.toString(),Feed.class);
            EventHandler.postEventOnMainThread(feed);
            CommentHandler.get().getCommentsForPost(feed.getId(),true);
        }
    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            EventHandler.postEventOnMainThread(new Feed());
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know if their is anything wrong with this pattern or if their is a better pattern I can use because I've heard a lot about singleton patterns not being a good pattern and I don't know how. But it works for me. This way I believe I'm not tying any network calls to the FeedsActivity or FeedsFragment to avoid memory leaks

Comment: try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: I've voted to close this as an opinion-based question. Most people dislike the singleton pattern (for good reason).

Comment: It's an anti-pattern and has certain uses, but you should not abuse it. Why do you *need* a `FeedHandler`? What does it *do*? Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton?rq=1 or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1

Comment: It is ok as long as you don't keep any reference to the view/context that can lead to memory leak

Comment: @cricket_007 I need it  to get Feeds from a Rest Api. I have edited my question to reflect that

Comment: Personally, I might try replacing Volley for Retrofit + Gson, then RxJava can complement your EventBus usage. I have not seen any recent usage of singletons for Retrofit. I could understand having one for the `Gson` object.

Comment: @cricket_007 I used Retrofit + Gson before Volley, I preferred Volley because it gave me more control. Over cache, response e.t.c

Comment: Okay, that's fine. You should know that the documentation covers how to create a [`GsonReqest`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) for Volley

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah I do. Thanks

Comment: private FeedHandler feedHandler=null; object should be private

Comment: Singleton pattern in android can cause memory leak by passing activityContext to it instead of applicationContext. Other than that it fully depends on your requirement whether it suits singleton function there or not.