# Node Singleton Use

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

The author of this article uses singletons for the service layer in this example Node api:

https://html5hive.org/how-to-create-rest-api-with-node-js-and-express/

He states, "We only want there to ever be one instance of our player service, so instead of exporting the class itself, we’ll export a new instance of it. Module files in node are only ever executed once, so this effectively gives us a singleton."

```
'use strict';

var uuid = require('node-uuid');

class PlayersService {
    constructor() {
        this.players = [];
    }

    getPlayers() {
        return this.players;
    }

    getSinglePlayer(playerId) {
        var player = this.players.filter(p => p.id === playerId)[0];

        return player || null;
    }

    addPlayer(info) {
        // prevent a bit of bad/duplicate data
        if (!info || this.players.filter(p => (p.firstName === info.firstName && p.lastName === info.lastName)).length > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        info.id = uuid.v4();

        this.players.push(info);
        return true;
    }

    updatePlayer(playerId, info) {
        var player = this.getSinglePlayer(playerId);
        if (player) {
            player.firstName = info.firstName ? info.firstName : player.firstName;
            player.lastName = info.lastName ? info.lastName : player.lastName;
            player.displayName = info.displayName ? info.displayName : player.displayName;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

module.exports = new PlayersService();
```

Which seems reasonable since the function of these services is to provide the same implementation for the controllers that use them.

However, in this post:

[On Design Patterns: When to use the Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton)

the poster asks for a legitimate use case for singletons other than a Logger class. Several people responded to his question by saying that singletons should never be used.

But isn't the use of singletons for services like the one I've copied here a legitimate use case and a best practice so that you are not creating multiple instances that provide the same implementation?  Thanks.

Comment: design patter depends on `use case`. The Link you provided clearly describe the use case of Singletons Patter.

Comment: It depends on how you want your application to shape up.. however one thing to notice that in nodejs, if you have a local module which has some block of code in the start and then module.exports function, it will execute the code above module.exports only once even if you require it multiple times/files for a same request. The module.exports will be executed everytime.. You can use this concept to manipulate singleton pattern

Comment: Also if your application is okay with having one instance and share the state of it across the application, go for singleton.. however each of your state is dynamic and going to have different properties, go for another like factory.