# C++ Singleton Design pattern alternatives

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I hate to beat a dead horse, that said, I've gone over so many conflicting articles over the past few days in regards to the use of the singleton pattern.

This question isn't be about which is the better choice in general, rather what makes sense for my use case.

The pet project I'm working on is a game. Some of the code that I'm currently working on, I'm leaning towards using a singleton pattern.

The use cases are as follows:

- a globally accessible logger.
- an OpenGL rendering manager.
- file system access.
- network access.
- etc.

Now for clarification, more than a couple of the above require shared state between accesses. For instance, the logger is wrapping a logging library and requires a pointer to the output log, the network requires an established open connection, etc.

Now from what I can tell it's more suggested that singletons be avoided, so lets look at how we may do that. A lot of the articles simply say to create the instance at the top and pass it down as a parameter to anywhere that is needed. While I agree that this is technically doable, my question then becomes, how does one manage the potentially massive number of parameters? Well what comes to mind is wrapping the different instances in a sort of "context" object and passing that, then doing something like `context->log("Hello World")`. Now sure that isn't to bad, but what if you have a sort of framework like so:

```
game_loop(ctx)
   ->update_entities(ctx)
        ->on_preupdate(ctx)
             ->run_something(ctx)
                 ->only use ctx->log() in some freak edge case in this function.
        ->on_update(ctx)
            ->whatever(ctx)
                 ->ctx->networksend(stuff)
   ->update_physics(ctx)
        ->ctx->networksend(stuff)
        //maybe ctx never uses log here.
```

You get the point... in some areas, some aspects of the "ctx" aren't ever used but you're still stuck passing it literally everywhere in case you may want to debug something down the line using logger, or maybe later in development, you actually want networking or whatever in that section of code.

I feel like the above example would much rather be suited to a globally accessible singleton, but I must admit, I'm coming from a C#/Java/JS background which may color my view. I want to adopt the mindset/best practices of a C++ programmer, yet like I said, I can't seem to find a straight answer. I also noticed that the articles that suggest just passing the "singleton" as a parameter only give very simplistic use cases that anyone would agree a parameter would be the better way to go.

In this game example, you probably wan't to access logging everywhere even if you don't plan on using it immediately. File system stuff may be all over but until you build out the project, it's really hard to say when/where it will be most useful.

So do I:

1. Stick with using singletons for these use cases regardless of how "evil/bad" people say it is.
2. Wrap everything in a context object, and pass it literally everywhere. (seems kinda gross IMO, but if that's the "more accepted/better" way of doing it, so be it.)
3. Something completely else. (Really lost as to what that might be.)

If option 1, from a performance standpoint, should I switch to using namespace functions, and hiding the "private" variables / functions in anonymous namespaces like most people do in C? (I'm guessing there will be a small boost in performance, but then I'll be stuck having to call an "init" and "destroy" method on a few of these rather than being able to just allow the constructor/destructor to do that for me, still might be worth while?)

Now I realize this may be a bit opinion based, but I'm hoping I can still get a relatively good answer when a more complicated/nested code base is in question.

**Edit:**
After much more deliberation I've decided to use the "Service Locator" pattern instead. To prevent a global/singleton of the Service Locator I'm making anything that may use the services inherit from a abstract base class that requires the Service Locator be passed when constructed.

I haven't implemented everything yet so I'm still unsure if I'll run into any problems with this approach, and would still love feedback on if this is a reasonable alternative to the singleton / global scope dilemma.

I had read that Service Locator is also somewhat of an anti-pattern, that said, many of the example I found implemented it with statics and/or as a singleton, perhaps using it as I've described removes the aspects that cause it to be an anti-pattern?

Comment: Given that this is a pet project and most likely you are working on it by yourself, my suggestion is to try both approaches and see what works for *you*. As noted, it is a conflicting topic - both approaches (using singleton or passing a context object) have advantages and disadvantages. In a team environment, it is much more difficult to decide because of the conflicting arguments, but you have the freedom to experiment.

Comment: Logging utility is commonly used as example where singletons are actually useful. And personally, I don't like absolutes. There's no such thing as "evil" pattern. Singleton [has many disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1), but it can also [be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-should-i-use-the-singleton?rq=1) in certain situations.

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov I find the best way to learn a programming language is through a personal project with it, although I know I can make both ways work, I'm more interested in what a more experienced C++ programmer who works in a team setting would prefer.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In the cases where a singleton pastern is useful. Would a more experienced C++ programmer go the rout of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4831051 approach, or use a namespace approach? Edit: I should mention, performance is a concern, but only if it does't have to many trade-offs. (I know this is left to opinion, but again, I'm interested in what a professional C++ developer would do in this situation.)

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you think you want to use a Singleton, ask yourself the following question: Why is it that it must be ensured at all cost that there never exists more than one instance of this class at any point in time? Because the whole point of the Singleton pattern is to make sure that there can never be more than one instance of the Singleton. That's what the term "singleton" is all about: there only being one. That's why it's called the Singleton pattern. That's why the pattern calls for the constructor to be private. The point of the Singleton pattern is *not* and never was to give you a globally-accessible instance of something. The fact that there is a global access point to the sole instance is just a consequence of the Singleton pattern. It is not the objective the Singleton pattern is meant to achieve. If all you want is a globally accessible instance of something, then use a global variable. That's exactly what global variables are for…

The Singleton pattern is probably the one design pattern that's singularly more often misunderstood than not. Is it an intrinsic aspect of the very concept of a network connection that there can only ever be one network connection at a time, and the world would come to an end if that constraint was ever to be violated? If the answer is no, then there is no justification for a network connection to ever be modeled as a Singleton. But don't take my word for it, convince yourself by checking out page 127 of *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* where the Singleton pattern was originally described…

Concerning your example: If you're ending up having to pass a massive number of parameters into some place then that first and foremost tells you one thing: there are too many responsibilities in that place. This fact is not changed by the use of Singletons. The use of Singletons simply obfuscates this fact because you're not forced to pass all stuff in through one door in the form of parameters but rather just access whatever you want directly all over the place. But you're still accessing these things. So the dependencies of your piece of code are the same. These dependencies are just not expressed explicitly anymore at some interface level but creep around in the mists. And you never know upfront what stuff a certain piece of code depends on until the moment your build breaks after trying to take away one thing that something else happened to depend upon. Note that this issue is not specific to the Singleton pattern. This is a concern with any kind of global entity in general…

So rather than ask the question of how to best pass a massive number of parameters, you should ask the question of why the hell does this one piece of code need access to that many things? For example, do you really need to explicitly pass the network connection to the game loop? Should the game loop not maybe just know the physics world object and that physics world object is at the moment of creation given some object that handles the network communication. And that object in turn is upon initialization told the network connection it is supposed to use? The log could just be a global variable (or is there really anything about the very idea of a log itself that prohibits there ever being more than one log?). Or maybe it would actually make sense for each thread to have its own log (could be a thread-local variable) so that you get a log from each thread in the order of the control flow that thread happened to take rather than some (at best) interleaved mess that would be the output from multiple threads for which you'd probably want to write some tool so that you'd at least have some hope of making sense of it at all…

Concerning performance, consider that, in a game, you'll typically have some parent objects that each manage collections of small child objects. Performance-critical stuff would generally be happening in places where something has to be done to all child objects in such a collection. The relative overhead of first getting to the parent object itself should generally be negligible…

PS: You might wanna have a look at the [Entity Component System pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system)…

Comment: I do plan on implementing the Entity Component System pattern, that said, their are many problems with most of the implementations that I've seen such as excessive pointer chasing, etc. Still trying to work out an implementation for that that won't suffer from pointer chase/cache misses/etc, also would like to come up with an implementation that separates the behavior from the state as I've read this can greatly increase parallel execution potential. Anyway, the ECS doesn't really make sense for all aspects of the game, the original question is for parts unrelated to it.