# Effective way to return an object that has a reference to another class object in C++

Tags: c++

I was trying to return an object `UnitCubeInstance`, which is an instance of a class `MeshObject`. The `MeshObject` has a reference to the `MeshAsset` class.

My current way of doing this is of no luck, and when the object is returned, the `MeshAsset` is no longer accessible.

My question is, is the design shown below viable in any way? Or do I have to make `MeshObject` to hold actual instances of `MeshAsset`, which seems easy to do but not efficient on the memory.

---

The problematic code:

```
static MeshObject createUnitCubeInstance(Program &program) {
    auto unitCubeAsset = MeshAsset::UnitCube();
    auto unitCubeInstance = MeshObject(unitCubeAsset);
    return unitCubeInstance;
}
```

And a minimal version of the two classes:

```
class MeshAsset {
    // returns a general instance that is designed to be shared, 
    // kind of resemble a singleton
    static MeshAsset UnitCube();
}

class MeshObject {
    MeshAsset& asset;
    MeshObject(MeshAsset& asset);
}
```

If I missed something that is crucial for my example, please feel free to comment.

Comment: I know C++ does not have ARC or stuff, and everything tends to be more manual, but I couldn't find how I could do it.

Comment: The `MeshObject` class you've shown us **does not** have a reference to anything. It doesn't have fields at all! Please post real code. Do you actually store `MeshAsset&` reference inside `MeshObject`? This won't work, because the `unitCubeAsset` variable dies after `createUnitCubeInstance` exits. Solutions are: either `UnitCube()` should return a (smart) pointer or you should make a copy inside `MeshObject` class.

Comment: @freakish thank you for pointing out! I added the `MeshAsset&` member to `MeshObject` class. I read some more posts, and realized that the `unitCubeAsset` will end its lifecycle after the function `createUnitCubeInstance` exits. Thank you for pointing out! I will look into smart pointer (haven't worked with it before).

Comment: I am reluctant to copy mesh asset to mesh object. Because each asset takes up MB of spaces, and there could easily be dozens or hundreds of them in the frame to be rendered (I should point out this is a computer graphics project)

Comment: @jackxujh This is a lifetime management problem. Somebody needs to be responsible for eventually cleaning up the `unitCubeAsset` you created. Right now that happens at the end of `createUnitCubeInstance`, which is too early. Maybe you want a central class that **owns** all created assets? Then (as long as said class lives longer than the `MeshObject`s) you can just store references in `MeshObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the local object you store a reference from is destroyed when you leave scope:

```
static MeshObject createUnitCubeInstance(Program &program) {
    auto unitCubeAsset = MeshAsset::UnitCube(); // <-- create a local object
    auto unitCubeInstance = MeshObject(unitCubeAsset); // <-- pass a local object as reference
    return unitCubeInstance; // pass object out
} // leave scope and break reference
```

Possible solutions:

- Store a copy of the `MeshAsset`.
- Create an object that actually outlives the local scope, e.g., via some working implementation of the singleton pattern: [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1008019/1025391) ([C++ Singleton Design pattern alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53977200/1025391))
- Have no fear to use dynamic allocation and (smart) pointers to control object lifetime, and share access and ownership to objects (I found this talk really insightful in this regard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE).

Just in case: you need to declare `auto& unitCubeAsset = ...` in case you want to store a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the JIC - I never realized `auto` also could have the form of `auto&`